# Is it possible to run npm script that is not executable?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I am having a problem with my PaaS.  When I deploy my node application my scripts are losing their executable bit.  I know in the long run my PaaS needs to fix this, but for now I am looking for a workaround.

I read this in the npm scripts documentation (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#exiting):

> Scripts are run by passing the line as a script argument to sh.

If I understand correctly the script run like this:

sh myscript.sh

If that is true the script does not need to be executable.  However if I run an npm script that is not executable.

npm run myscript

I get this:

> sh: bin/myscript.sh: Permission denied

Is there a way around this?

EDIT:  here is my simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
```

Comment: What's the content of myscript.sh? Is it a bash script?

Answer (score 2):

Try in your package.json a line like this:

```
"myscript": "sh bin/myscript.sh"
```

I think the fine print here is that npm is running your command as `sh -c 'line from package.json here'`, which if that is just a file path, `sh` will require it to be executable. However, without `-c`, `sh` will run a non-executable shell script without error.

```
sh -c 'bin/myscript.sh'
sh: bin/myscript.sh: Permission denied

sh -c 'sh bin/myscript.sh'
myscript is running
```